# Remove the class of one element and assign it to another using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove the *selected* class of an `<a>` and assign it the last `<a>` instead. Both are nested within individual `<li>` elements.

Here's an example of the code:

```
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
   <li class="tab"><a href="#one" class="selected">Home</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#two">About</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#three">Profile</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#four">History</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#five">The Beginning of V-Cube</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this using JavaScript/jQuery? Please advise.

**EDIT:**

Let's say I don't want to target the last tab specifically. Can the href be used as a selector instead?

**EDIT #2:**

Thank you so much everyone for the quick response. All your answers were spot on, wish I could mark them all as answers :)

Comment: At what point in time do you want this reattribution to occur? Any event's in particular like click/mousedown?

Comment: of course yes `a[href="VALUEOFYOURHREF"]`

Comment: This should occur during the page load event. The idea is to show a different active tab on first load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove class from an element, use [**removeClass**](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

To get the last element, use [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector or [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/). To add new class to element use [**addClass**](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```js
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');

$('.tabs li:last a').addClass('selected');
// OR
// $('.tabs li').last().children('a').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#one" class="selected">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#two">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#three">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#four">History</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#five">The Beginning of V-Cube</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**Update**

> Let's say I don't want to target the last tab specifically. Can the href be used as a selector instead?

```
$('.tabs a[href="#five"]').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
$(".tabs li").first().find("a").removeClass("selected");
$(".tabs li").last().find("a").addClass("selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
   <li class="tab"><a href="#one" class="selected">Home</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#two">About</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#three">Profile</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#four">History</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#five">The Beginning of V-Cube</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.clearfix').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$('.clearfix').find('li:last').find('a').addClass('selected');
$("a[href$='five']").addClass('bold');
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
  <li class="tab"><a href="#one" class="selected">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#two">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#three">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#four">History</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tab"><a href="#five">The Beginning of V-Cube</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Just use `.removeClass() and .addClass()`

`.removeClass()`

> Remove a single class, multiple classes, or all classes from each element in the set of matched elements.

`.addClass()`

> Description: Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: @Tushar which is better as selector `$('.clearfix').find('li:last').find('a')` or `$('.clearfix').find('li a:last')` I will update the answer if necessary

Comment: I think `$('.clearfix').find('li:last').find('a')`, the reason is that you'll narrow down the search for `a` by selecting a single `li`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var classname = $(".tabs li:first-child a").attr("class");
   console.log(classname);
   $(".tabs li:last-child a").addClass(classname);
   $(".tabs li:first-child a").removeClass();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
   <li class="tab"><a href="#one" class="selected">Home</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#two">About</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#three">Profile</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#four">History</a></li>
   <li class="tab"><a href="#five">The Beginning of V-Cube</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is quite easy also in vanilla JS:

```
document.querySelector('.selected').classList.remove('selected');

document.querySelector('.tabs li:last a').classList.add('selected');
```

If you want to use an arbitrary `a` and select the attribute href then you should use this selector:

`a[href="HREFVALUE"]`